# How to initiate a flush of all invalidated observers in the middle of loop?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm writing a shiny application that needs to send data to the client in the middle of a longer computation. The setup is so that during a for loop data is added to a list and a reactive value is elevated to signal that new data has arrived. An observer is depending on the reactive value and set to take the last added data and send it to the client. A pseudo setup is something along the lines of this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    dataAdded <- reactiveValues(counter=0)
    dataStore <- list()

    dataGenerator <- observe({
        if(input$analysisButton == 0) return(c())

        files <- isolate({input$datafiles})

        for(i in files) {
            result <- doExpensiveAnalysis(i)
            index <- length(dataStore)+1
            dataStore[[index]] <<- result
            dataAdded$counter <<- isolate(dataAdded$counter)+1
        }
    })
    data <- reactive({
        index <- dataAdded$counter
        if(index != 0) {
            do.call('renderData', dataStore[[length(dataStore)]])
        }
    })
    output$result <- reactive({data()})
}
```

The hope is that after each iteration of the for-loop the data() conductor will be re-evaluated as it depends on dataAdded$counter. Sadly the re-evaluation only happens once the whole loop is completed, resulting in only the last iteration being send to the client.

I have tried adding shiny:::flushReact() to the loop to no effect...